# segfault on vector<struct>

Tags: c++, linux, vector, struct

I created a struct to hold some data and then declared a vector to hold that struct.

But when I do a push_back I get damn segfault and I have no idea why!

My struct is defines as:

```
typedef struct Group
{
    int codigo;
    string name;
    int deleted;
    int printers;
    int subpage;

    /*included this when it started segfaulting*/
    Group(){ name.reserve(MAX_PRODUCT_LONG_NAME); }
    ~Group(){ name.clear(); }
    Group(const Group &b)
    {
    codigo = b.codigo;
    name = b.name;
    deleted = b.deleted;
    printers = b.printers;
    subpage = b.subpage;
    }
   /*end of new stuff*/
 };
```

Originally, the struct didn't have the copy, constructor or destructor. I added them latter when I read this post below.

[Seg fault after is item pushed onto STL container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676575/seg-fault-after-is-item-pushed-onto-stl-container)

but the end result is the same.

There is one this that is bothering me as hell! When I first push some data into the vector, everything goes fine. Later on in the code when I try to push some more data into the vector, my app just segfaults!

The vector is declared

```
vector<Group> Groups
```

and is a global variable to the file where I am using it. No externs anywhere else, etc...

I can trace the error to:

```
_M_deallocate(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage- this->_M_impl._M_start);
```

in vector.tcc when I finish adding/copying the last element to the vector....

As far as I can tell. I shouldn't be needing anything to do with a copy constructor as a shallow copy should be enough for this. I'm not even allocating any space (but I did a reserve for the string to try out).

I have no idea what the problem is!

I'm running this code on OpenSuse 10.2 with gcc 4.1.2

I'm not really to eager to upgrade gcc because of backward compatibility issues...

This code worked "perfectly" on my windows machine. I compiled it with gcc 3.4.5 mingw without any problems...

help!

--- ... ---

:::EDIT:::

I push data

```
Group tmp_grp;

(...)

tmp_grp.name = "Nova ";
tmp_grp.codigo=GetGroupnextcode();
tmp_grp.deleted=0;
tmp_grp.printers=0;
tmp_grp.subpage=0;
Groups.push_back(tmp_grp);
```

Comment: Show the code that pushes it please.

Comment: Your struct dos not need the copy constructor, and it is a bad idea to provide it - the default copy constructor does everything you need. You also don't need the typedef on the struct. It also doesn't need the destructor, and probably not the constructor that takes a size.

Comment: @Neil. I know! I added them out of "desperation"

Comment: Is this code multi-threaded? And do you do any explicit memory allocation in it with new/delete?

Comment: Upvoting as one of the best presented "this doesn't work" questions I've seen on SO.  I suspect you'd prefer an answer, but right now all I can do is upvote.

Comment: You're corrupting the heap somewhere else and it's just coincidentally crashing when your vector tries to deallocate some memory, I'd say.  If you're not using pointers anywhere, maybe you're overflowing a buffer.

Comment: I don't like the `typedef struct Group` as it should only be `struct Group`.  Perhaps it's parsing that portion wrong and then messing up the reading of the next code?  It almost looks as if you're typedefing Group to be a struct, then declaring an anonymous struct.  However, that would totally bazooka your build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

valgrind to the rescue! What called out to me in the valgrind log was this piece.

```
Invalid write of size 4
==4639==    at 0x805BDC0: ChangeGroups() (articles.cpp:405)
==4639==    by 0x80AC008: GeneralConfigChange() (config.cpp:4474)
==4639==    by 0x80EE28C: teste() (main.cpp:2259)
==4639==    by 0x80EEBB3: main (main.cpp:2516)
```

At this point in the file I was doing this

```
Groups[oldselected].subpage=SL.selected_code();
```

and what if oldselected was outside the bounds of the vector?

In this case what was happening was that oldselected could be -1... and although this wasn't crashing at this point, it was writing something somewhere else...

I should probably start using the at() operator and check for the exception or just check if "oldselected" is >0 and < Groups.size() [preferred solution].

So kudos to John and Josh for reminding me of valgrind.

I've used it before, but never needed to do anything t significant with it (fortunately :D).

It's interesting that in windows I don't get this segfault. The problem was the same... I guess that it has something to do with memory management and the compiler... it really eludes me.

Thanks everyone for the input ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Like Neil said, you don't need a default constructor, copy constructor, or destructor:

- `std::string` cleans up after itself, so your destructor is never necessary.
- The compiler-provided shallow copy constructor will work just fine.
- `std::string::reserve` is unnecessary, since `std::string` will dynamically allocate memory as needed, but it *may* provide a performance benefit.

The code that you posted looks correct (and it looks very simple and straightforward, so it's hard to see where an error could creep in).  Therefore, I suspect that you're corrupting memory elsewhere in your code and that the `vector<Group>` is simply the victim.

Try installing [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (OpenSuse should provide a package for it) and run your application through it (from the command line, just run `valgrind my-app`) to see if Valgrind can catch any memory corruption.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely remove the destructor. C++ will automatically call the destructor of all data members, and doing things to members that already have a destructor like that is unnecessary and could be unsafe.

But, I don't see anything wrong with your code per-se. You will have to post a little more of it. Try expanding the (...) section - show us all the code that involves the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Memory errors like this can be caused by deleting the same memory twice or deleting memory you didn't get from new. The errors often occur long after the fact in places like this. As DeadMG already stated install valgrind and look for other seemingly unrelated memory problems.