# Segfault when pushing to member vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, push-back

Here's a relatively small but segfaulting project. I've searched quite a few posts doing similar things and while many seemed to be having the same problem, none solved my problem.

The basic issue is this: I have an object (`myGraph`) with a member vector, and a few methods. A method inside another class invokes one of `myGraph`'s methods, which in turn invokes another one. Inside *that* function, a push is made to a vector of ints in `myGraph`. However, this push results in a segfault.

In a somewhat extreme measure, I've been commenting out large portions of code (on a fresh branch of course) and have reduced my code down to a sparse few items. ([other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739354/segfault-on-vectorstruct) seemed to indicate that this kind of thing might be caused by bad code elsewhere) yet I am still getting a segfault.

What follow are the watered-down files, composed of the few things remaining uncommented. I say "watered-down" because a lot of declarations (of now-empty functions and such) have been removed. If you need additional information (for instance, if it's important - somehow - that I'm using a virtual function somewhere... as a radical example) just let me know.

in Dispatcher.h:

```
class myGraph;

class CDispatcher
{
public:
    CDispatcher(void);
    ~CDispatcher(void);

    void ProcessCall(string buf);

    myGraph* mymap;

};
```

in Dispatcher.cpp:

```
void CDispatcher::ProcessCall(string buf) 
{
    mymap->getDistance(0,1);
};
```

in mygraph.cpp:

```
int myGraph::getDistance(int start, int end) {
    Dijkstras(start,end);

    // This is just to return something
    return 5;
};

vector<int> myGraph::Dijkstras(int startVert,int endVert) {

    vertices_i.push_back(2); // This line results in a segfault
    cout << "push successful" << endl;

    // This is just to return something
    vector<int> unvisited;
    return unvisited;
};
```

mygraph.h:

```
typedef struct edge
{
    int endVert;
    int weight;
} edge;


typedef struct vertex
{
    long dist;
    bool visited;
    int prev;

    vector<edge> edges;
} vertex;
class myGraph
{
public:
    myGraph(int initSize);
    ~myGraph(void);

    int getDistance(int start, int end);
    vector<int> Dijkstras(int startVert,int endVert);

    //vector<vertex> vertices; // The original vector that was segfaulting
    vector<int> vertices_i; // Simpler vector, of just ints. Still segfaults

};
```

Comment: Please show the code for `CDispatcher(void);`

Comment: It's an empty constructor. Do I need something there?

Comment: Yes, you do :):):) See Ernest's answer below...

Comment: Yep, you were spot on :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unavoidable conclusion is that the member pointer `myGraph* mymap` is pointing to garbage; you've apparently neglected to initialize it to point to a `myGraph` object. You need to create an object for it to refer to in the `CDispatcher` constructor -- i.e.,

```
CDispatcher(void) : mymap(new myGraph(1)) {}
```

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense. Added this, got an error back and added an int (myGraph expects one in its constructor, I was about to ragequit haha) and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Now excuse me while I go review Chapter One, Section One of pointers: "A pointer is NOT an object". -.-' Can't believe I spent this long and eliminated that much code, and still didn't figure it out. :(